# Magento2 move the block from right to left without removing

Tags: magento2

I need to move the Compare products and My Wish list blocks to the left of the page.

I have my page like, where my Compare products should come to the right:

[image]

I did something like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <move element="category.product.addto" destination="product.info.media" /> 
   </body>
</page>
```

But im not sure if destination element is proper, but the Compare product block is not moving!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the layout of the page to `2columns-left`

You can override the layout like this:

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

and change the layout like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

</page>
```

Comment: Have updated the answer @Sejal, but the block hasnt moved

Comment: Can you check if the body has this class? page-layout-2columns-left. If the class is present but the block is not moving then we have to do it via css.

Comment: Whats the correct destination name in my scenario?

Comment: Lets solve issues one by one. First try to move compare and wishlist from right to left by specifying the layout to "2columns-left"

Comment: Yes i have updated in my question as page layout to 2column-left itself

Comment: Can you check if the body has this class? page-layout-2columns-left

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59108/discussion-between-sejal-shah-and-sachin-s).